# ggplot vertically justify legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been looking at this for awhile now. My legends are running out of the chart area. Is there a way to vertically justify legend in ggplot2?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:30, y = 1:30, color = letters[1:30])
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = color)) +
    guides(col = guide_legend(nrow = 30))
```

Comment: Isn't this related to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12202683/420055) (in which case you could simply update it instead of posting a new one)?

Comment: This comes top when googling ``"ggplot legend vertical"`` so I made the example self-contained and updated it to current ``ggplot2`` syntax.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Playing around with `legend.direction` ("vertical"/"horizontal") should work:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:30, y = 1:30, color = letters[1:30])
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = color)) +
    theme(legend.direction='horizontal')
```

You may also want to combine it with `legend.box`("horizontal"/"vertical").

If you want to control the absolute position of the legend, add:

```
theme(legend.direction = "vertical",
legend.box = "horizontal",
legend.position = c(0.025,0.975),
legend.justification = c(0, 1))
```

Which, for example, places the legend inside the top left corner of the graph.